# What is the significance of this form of Sri Krishna at Udupi?

Tags: krishna, temple

[image]

What is the significance of this form of Sri Krishna at Udupi? Kindly cite authentic source.

Comment: Significance? Is it fine if I tell the reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Sri Krishna temple at Udupi, [Sri Krishna is decorated](https://m.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=avAv3SrTEPE) (alankara) in different forms one among them is Durgaroopadhari Sri Krishna (which is asked in question). In this video, many forms are shown.

[During navaratri](https://sripalimarumatha.org/daily-darshana/durgaroopadhari-shri-krishna) (nine nights), Sri Krishna is decorated in feminine forms according to the days dedicated to goddess, like Durga, Lakshmi, Saraswati, Mohini etc.